# How to build new types by expand a parameter pack together with another list of types?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a parameter packed fuction as follows,

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(const Args&... args)
{   
   bar( SomeClass<Args, ??> { args }... );
}
```

Without the `??` part above, this is a normal parameter pack expansion.

However, I would like ?? to be a type from `typedef std::tuple<(a list of types computed somewhere else)> typeLists;`, with the same sequence as the parameter pack.

I.e., for the first type in parameter pack, ?? should be the first type in `typeLists`, etc.

It's ensured that the number of types in `typeLists` is the same as the size of parameter pack.

Is there a way to implement this? I read some similar questions but none is exactly the same. I think it probably requires to use `index_sequence` but I'm not sure how.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you limited to C++17? C++20 template lambdas make this way easier. Also, using a `tuple` like this is probably bad for build times. Make an empty struct template to represent type lists.

Comment: Try `SomeClass<??, Args...>{args...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it probably requires to use `index_sequence` but I'm not sure
> how.

Yes, it's very easy to do this using `index_sequence`:

```
template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
void foo_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Args&... args)
{   
   using typeLists = std::tuple<Args...>;
   bar( SomeClass<Args, std::tuple_element_t<Is, typeLists>>{ args }... );
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(const Args&... args)
{   
   foo_impl( std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}, args... );
}
```